# unique column value per row

Tags: django, django-models

I find it best to use an example, so here we go:

Say I have a table with chores and a table with a weekly schedule like this:

```
CHORES:
|----+---------------+----------+-------|
| id |      name     |   type   | hours |
|----+---------------+----------+-------|
| 1  | clean kitchen | cleaning |   4   |
|----+---------------+----------+-------|
| 2  | clean toilet  | cleaning |   3   |
etc

SCHEDULE:
|------+---------------+---------------+-----|
| week |     monday    |    tuesday    | etc |
|------+---------------+---------------+-----|
|   1  | clean kitchen | clean toilet  | etc |
|------+---------------+---------------+-----|
|   2  | clean toilet  | clean kitchen | etc |
etc
```

I want  to make sure that for one week, you can't have duplicate cells, so this wouldn't be allowed:

```
SCHEDULE:
|------+---------------+--------------+-----|
| week |     monday    |   tuesday    | etc |
|------+---------------+--------------+-----|
|   1  | clean toilet  | clean toilet | etc |

etc
```

What would I have to do  in my models.py to get this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try django unique-together in model meta option.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#unique-together

Answer (score 1):

I'd better user ManyToMany through another table like that:

```
SCHEDULE:
 ------+------------------------+
| week |     chores             |    
|------+------------------------+
|   1  | many to many to chores |
|------+------------------------+
|   2  | many to many to chores |
```

And trough table like that

```
THROUGH TABLE:
|---------+---------------+---------------+
| week_id |  day of week  |    chores_id  |
|---------+---------------+---------------+
|   1     | Monday        | clean toilet  |
|---------+---------------+---------------+
|   1     | Tuesday       | clean kitchen |
```

And in that table make unique together for week_id and chores_id